# Can I use mini profiler for ASP.NET Web API and have results still seen on URL?

Tags: mvc-mini-profiler

I am hitting an ASP.NET web api controller from a rest client, and I am not able to view the stats of this call in the Mini Profiler URL: /mini-profiler-resources/results.  Is this not possible?

Comment: You application is hosted in ? OWIN, IIS ? Where ?